# Is it possible to do so?

Tags: java, stream, java-stream

I have a list of nested classes. Can I use streams to traverse into them and when the condition is true, I need to print all values.

Input  : List ObjDS;

Instead of using loops or iterator , can we use streams to traverse and when d1 + d2 of Obj4 in each is equals to some number (say 10) , then print a1,a2,b1,b2,c1,c2,d1,d2 of the hierarchy .

Is it possible to do with streams ?

```
public class ObjA {
    int a1;
    int a2;
}

public class ObjB {
    int b1;
    int b2;
    List<ObjA> objAS;
}

public class ObjC {
    int c1;
    int c2;
    List<ObjB> objBS;
}

public class ObjD {
    int d1;
    int d2;
    List<ObjC> objCS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it is possible.

**NOTE**: What I understood from your question is that you want to print all the fields of all the objects inside ObjD object where ObjD.d1 + ObjD.d2 equals some particular sum. I hope I have understood your query correctly.

It is actually easy to achieve this with the filter method from Streams API.

The code will look something like this:

```
int sum = 10;
objDS.stream()
     .filter(objD -> objD.d1 + objD.d2 == sum)
     .forEach(objD -> {
         List<ObjC> objCS = objD.objCS;
         objCS.forEach(objC -> {
             List<ObjB> objBS = objC.objBS;
             objBS.forEach(objB -> {
                 List<ObjA> objAS = objB.objAS;
                 objAS.forEach(objA -> {
                     System.out.println("ObjA.a1: " + objA.a1);
                     System.out.println("ObjA.a2: " + objA.a2);
                 });
                 System.out.println("ObjB.b1: " + objB.b1);
                 System.out.println("ObjB.b2: " + objB.b2);
             });
             System.out.println("ObjC.c1: " + objC.c1);
             System.out.println("ObjC.c1: " + objC.c1);
         });
         System.out.println("ObjD.d1: " + objD.d1);
         System.out.println("ObjD.d2: " + objD.d2);
     });
```

Here, I am using the sum variable to check the condition you have mentioned. Once the list of ObjD is filtered, we only have the objects where ObjD.d1 + ObjD.d2 equals sum.

Further, we can simply use the forEach() method to iterate over each list and according to your preference print the variables in any order you want.

Here, I start by printing the innermost list of ObjAS followed by ObjBS, ObjCS and ObjDS.

You can change the order as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify your requirements a bit more in detail. In my understanding, you cannot just print `abcd`, but instead want to print a whole tree under a `d`. The flattest way I can think of at first glance is this:

```
ds  .stream()
    .filter(d -> d.d1 + d.d2 == sum)
    .peek(d -> System.out.println(d.d1 + " " + d.d2))
    .flatMap(d -> d.objCS.stream())
    .peek(c -> System.out.println(" " + c.c1 + " " + c.c2))
    .flatMap(c -> c.objBS.stream())
    .peek(b -> System.out.println("  " + b.b1 + " " + b.b2))
    .flatMap(b -> b.objAS.stream())
    .forEach(a -> System.out.println("   " + a.a1 + " " + a.a2));
```

You might want to think of using some common super class to make this code less redundant ([composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern)). You could also write a print methods that call each other (As in, you call `objD.print()`, which prints `d1` and `d2` and then calls `objCS.foreach(ObjC::print())`, which in turn...). [Tree traversal algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Post-order_(LRN)) might also be a good read.